# Create a bridged network connection using only the command line

Tags: windows-server-2008, command-line-interface, hyper-v, bridge, windows-server-core

I want to bridge two network connections on a Microsoft Hyper-V Server 2008 R2. As I'm essentially using a "Server Core", GUI is not available, so I can't use the usual way. (Right click the network connections and select bridging). Also the `netsh bridge` command is only available if you have already created a bridged connection, and you cannot create a new one with that command. Any suggestions?

Comment: There is technically a GUI available for managing Core. http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/guyt/archive/2008/03/22/windows-server-core-coreconfigurator-to-the-rescue.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The [Technet documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754586%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) claims that `Network Bridge can be set up or removed only through Network Connections`. Although there obviously must be some API (probably even a WMI API as [this article](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/microsoft/Win32-Networks/29757373/wmi-and-network-bridging.aspx) is suggesting) for this purpose that the network connections control panel is calling, it seems undocumented.

I'd try the reverse-engineering route and just use [process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896645) to see what registry values are changed by creating a bridge via the GUI and try to replay this on a different machine to see how it behaves.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Powershell module for managing Hyper-V.  Information on that is [Seems](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/Video/ff955836)

Comment: That module is for managing Hyper-V related stuff, like creating and removing Viwrtual Network Interfaces. I couldn't find stuff that manage the core system (like creating bridged connections).